# Inconsistent results using dot notation in Firestore (setData vs updateData)

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

**UPDATE**

I was experiencing inconsistencies with Firestore's dot notation and have learned that we must use literal notation when using the `setData` operation and can use dot notation when using the `updateData` operation.

The following operation was ignoring dot notation:

```
...setData(
    ["someMap.\(someId)": FieldValue.increment(Int64(-1))]
, forDocument: Firestore.firestore().collection("someDocument").document(userId), merge: true)

someMap: ["x34JF2ko0sPLnbfoijw": 1] // not decremented
someMap.x34JF2ko0sPLnbfoijw: -1 // instead, new number field created
```

To remedy the problem, we must simply use literal notation:

```
...setData(
    ["someMap": [someId: FieldValue.increment(Int64(-1))]
, forDocument: Firestore.firestore().collection("someDocument").document(userId), merge: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has changed with dot notation, but it apparently doesn't work with `setValue()`.  As far as I can see, it's only documented to work with [updateData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) - you can see examples in that link to the documentation.

So, what you will have to do if you want to update that nested field is something like this:

```
transaction.setData(
    [ "interactionCounts.\(eventId)": FieldValue.increment(Int64(-1)) ],
    forDocument: Firestore.firestore().collection("trackers").document(userId)
)
```

I don't do swift programming, but I confirmed that similar code operates correctly for nodejs `update()` vs. `set()` with merge.

If you are absolutely certain that this worked with `setData()` in the past, I recommend you [file an issue with the iOS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk).